# Trying to change the looks of my Android Buttons

Tags: android-widget

I would like to display some Android button widgets on top of my application data, but to do that I need to change the way they look.  I would like the buttons to be transparent, except for the label and a frame around the edge (both drawn in WHITE seems appropriate).

The transparency and label parts were obvious and easy, but the frame part has got me defeated so far.  The result of this is my transparent buttons look like text hanging in space -- which seems less than cool...

If I were drawing shapes on a Canvas, I could use paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE) and then drawRoundRect() will draw just the edge of the rectangle -- pretty much exactly the way I want.  However, I have no idea how to (or if it's possible to) apply this concept to the XML that lays out my UI buttons.

Any suggestions??  Have I exceeded the capabilities of the XML files in my project, and thus need to do this programmatically??

Thanks,
R.

EDIT:  Well, this isn't looking good... Nobody's got nothing???

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, take a linearlayout, and give the color of the frame you want. add to it a padding of 1px, and place the button inside it. you get your border

Comment: Well, I'll certainly give that a try, thanks.  (The Linear Layout is already there, so that's a bonus)...  One question, though: Will this outline the buttons individually, or will it create a single box around the group??

Comment: if u wrap each button in a linear layout then each button, else the whole group :)

Comment: I tried it once, but I must be doing something wrong, because the result was a fat white rectangle.  Are the parameters I need to set android:padding and android:background?

Comment: padding and background for the linearlayout

Comment: Sadly, it would appear this isn't possible, because my buttons are transparent.  Since the buttons are transparent, any color implemented on the underlying layout is all you see.  It blots out the button completely.  I'll have to find another way to implement this, but thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: hey! y dont u try using the stroke property? That shud give u the effect u desire!

Comment: Certainly doesn't sound like a bad idea, but I don't know how to apply STROKE (instead of FILL) to a button.  I do know how to do that manually drawing a Rect or RectF in a canvas, but I can't find how to apply that knowledge.  Any suggestions?